# Select class having maximum students enrolled in it

Tags: mysql, sql

The Basic Structure of tables are

```
Student ( snum, sname, major, age, admission_date )
```

and

`Class ( cname,snum meets_at, room, fid )`

We have to find

Select class having maximum students enrolled in it.

Comment: So do you have a question about how to do this?  Where are you having trouble? What have you tried?

Comment: And why does this sound like a homework assignment?

Comment: So is it Sql Server or MySql? Hmmm, Schrödinger connection string?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and specify if its mySQL or SQL Server... We'll help people with homework, but you have to show effort first.

Comment: I am asking how to do so and it is for mysql

Comment: Removed sql-server tag; please read -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried select cname from class group by cname having count(snum) = (select max(snum) from class group by cname); Plz help

Comment: How should ties for first be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple

```
    Select cname,Count(snum) From
    Class 
    Group By cname
   Order by Count(snum) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: soory use order by instead og having